# jScrollPane keep snaps to the bottom

Tags: swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I tried to retrieve data from database and display using textArea with scrollPane. Here is my code :

```
public class eForumThreadContent {

private JFrame jFrame = null; // @jve:decl-index=0:visual-constraint="74,36"
private JPanel jContentPane = null;
private JLabel jLoginLink = null;
private JTextField jTextField_search = null;
private JButton jButtonSearch = null;
private JLabel jLabel_sessionborder = null;
private JButton jButton_home = null;
private JLabel jLabel_searchBackgroundColor = null;
private JButton jButton_signOut = null;
private JButton jButton_postNewThread = null;
private JButton jButton_back = null;
private JLabel jLabel_replyBy = null;
private JLabel jLabel_username = null;
private JLabel jLabel_reply = null;
private JTextArea jTextArea_reply = null;
private JButton jButton_postReply = null;
private JTable jTableComment = null;
private JScrollPane jScrollPaneComment = null;
private JButton jButton_bookmark = null;
private JButton jButton_myAcc = null;
private  String userName; // @jve:decl-index=0:
DBController db = new DBController();  //  @jve:decl-index=0:
private  int topicId;
private JLabel jLabel_topicTitle = null;
private JLabel jLabel_topicBy = null;
private JLabel jLabel_separator = null;
private JLabel jLabel_title = null;
private JScrollPane jScrollPane_areaScrollPane = null;
private JTextArea jTextArea_content = null;
private JScrollPane jScrollPane_descContent = null;
/**
 * This method initializes jFrame
 * 
 * @return javax.swing.JFrame
 */
JFrame getJFrame() {
    if (jFrame == null) {
        jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setSize(new Dimension(946, 762));
        jFrame.setContentPane(getJContentPane());
        jFrame.setTitle("eForum");
    }
    return jFrame;
}

/**
 * This method initializes jContentPane
 * 
 * @return javax.swing.JPanel
 */
private JPanel getJContentPane() {
    if (jContentPane == null) {
        jLabel_title = new JLabel();
        jLabel_title.setBounds(new Rectangle(75, 167, 77, 51));
        jLabel_title.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        jLabel_title.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        jLabel_title.setText("Title : ");
        jLabel_separator = new JLabel();
        jLabel_separator.setBounds(new Rectangle(73, 278, 784, 8));
        jLabel_separator.setBackground(new Color(102,102,102));
        jLabel_separator.setOpaque(true);
        jLabel_topicBy = new JLabel();
        jLabel_topicBy.setBounds(new Rectangle(761, 217, 175, 41));
        jLabel_topicBy.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        jLabel_topicTitle = new JLabel();
        jLabel_topicTitle.setBounds(new Rectangle(161, 167, 757, 50));
        jLabel_topicTitle.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        jLabel_reply = new JLabel();
        jLabel_reply.setBounds(new Rectangle(106, 528, 132, 37));
        jLabel_reply.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        jLabel_reply.setText("Comment");
        jLabel_username = new JLabel();
        jLabel_username.setBounds(new Rectangle(256, 483, 315, 32));
        jLabel_username.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        jLabel_username.setText(userName);
        jLabel_replyBy = new JLabel();
        jLabel_replyBy.setBounds(new Rectangle(106, 481, 137, 38));
        jLabel_replyBy.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        jLabel_replyBy.setText("Reply by");
        jLabel_searchBackgroundColor = new JLabel();
        jLabel_searchBackgroundColor
                .setBounds(new Rectangle(2, 64, 930, 44));
        jLabel_searchBackgroundColor
                .setBackground(new Color(102, 102, 102));
        jLabel_searchBackgroundColor.setOpaque(true);
        jLabel_sessionborder = new JLabel();
        jLabel_sessionborder.setBounds(new Rectangle(-1, 40, 930, 25));
        jLabel_sessionborder.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0,
                0, 1, 0, Color.black));
        jLabel_sessionborder.setText("");
        jLoginLink = new JLabel();
        jLoginLink.setBounds(new Rectangle(34, 34, 259, 25));
        jLoginLink.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 0, 0,
                Color.black));
        jLoginLink.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        jLoginLink.setText("Logged in as " + userName);
        jContentPane = new JPanel();
        jContentPane.setLayout(null);
        jContentPane.setBackground(Color.white);
        jContentPane.add(jLoginLink, null);
        jContentPane.add(getJTextField_search(), null);
        jContentPane.add(getJButtonSearch(), null);
        jContentPane.add(jLabel_sessionborder, null);
        jContentPane.add(getJButton_home(), null);
        jContentPane.add(jLabel_searchBackgroundColor, null);
        jContentPane.add(getJButton_signOut(), null);
        jContentPane.add(getJButton_postNewThread(), null);
        jContentPane.add(getJButton_back(), null);
        jContentPane.add(jLabel_replyBy, null);
        jContentPane.add(jLabel_username, null);
        jContentPane.add(jLabel_reply, null);
        jContentPane.add(getJTextArea_reply(), null);
        jContentPane.add(getJButton_postReply(), null);
        jContentPane.add(getJScrollPaneComment(), null);
        jContentPane.add(getJButton_bookmark(), null);
        jContentPane.add(getJButton_myAcc(), null);
        jContentPane.add(jLabel_topicTitle, null);
        jContentPane.add(jLabel_topicBy, null);
        jContentPane.add(jLabel_separator, null);
        jContentPane.add(jLabel_title, null);
        jContentPane.add(getJScrollPane_areaScrollPane(), null);
        jContentPane.add(getJTextArea_content(), null);
        jContentPane.add(getJScrollPane_descContent(), null);
        SetUpTopicDetails();
    }
    return jContentPane;
}

/**
 * This constructor take in the userName from eForumLogin page. The username
 * will be display in jLoginLink.
 * 
 * @param userName
 */
public eForumThreadContent(String userName, int topicId) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.topicId = topicId;

}

/**
 * This method initializes jTextField_search
 * 
 * @return javax.swing.JTextField
 */
private JTextField getJTextField_search() {
    if (jTextField_search == null) {
        jTextField_search = new JTextField(50);
        jTextField_search.setDocument (new JTextFieldLimit(50));
        jTextField_search.setBounds(new Rectangle(500, 75, 285, 29));
        jTextField_search.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    }
    return jTextField_search;
}

/**
 * This method initializes jButtonSearch submitSearch is called when this
 * button is on click.
 * 
 * @return javax.swing.JButton
 */
private JButton getJButtonSearch() {
    if (jButtonSearch == null) {
        jButtonSearch = new JButton();
        jButtonSearch.setBounds(new Rectangle(797, 73, 114, 28));
        jButtonSearch.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        jButtonSearch.setText("Search");
        jButtonSearch
                .addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                        submitSearch(e);
                    }
                });
    }
    return jButtonSearch;
}


public void submitSearch(ActionEvent e) {
    String search = jTextField_search.getText();
    if (search.equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Please enter keyword to search");
    } else {
        eForumSearch searchResult = new eForumSearch(userName, search);
        if (searchResult.searchKeyword() == true) {
            getJFrame().dispose();
            eForumSearchResult myWindow = new eForumSearchResult(userName,
                    search);
            myWindow.getJFrame().setVisible(true);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No results found");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This method initializes jButton_home
 * 
 * @return javax.swing.JButton
 */
private JButton getJButton_home() {
    if (jButton_home == null) {
        jButton_home = new JButton();
        jButton_home.setBounds(new Rectangle(819, 2, 94, 60));
        jButton_home.setBackground(Color.white);
        jButton_home.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
        jButton_home.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
                "/Home.png")));
        jButton_home
        .addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                getJFrame().dispose();
                kioskHomepage myWindow = new kioskHomepage();
                myWindow.getJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    return jButton_home;
}

private JButton getJButton_signOut() {
    if (jButton_signOut == null) {
        jButton_signOut = new JButton();
        jButton_signOut.setBounds(new Rectangle(297, 35, 139, 24));
        jButton_signOut.setText("Sign out");
        jButton_signOut.setBorderPainted(false);
        jButton_signOut.setOpaque(false);
        jButton_signOut.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        jButton_signOut.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        jButton_signOut.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        jButton_signOut
                .addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                        getJFrame().dispose();
                        eForumSignOut myWindow = new eForumSignOut(userName);
                        myWindow.getJFrame().setVisible(true);

                    }
                });
    }
    return jButton_signOut;
}

private JButton getJButton_postNewThread() {
    if (jButton_postNewThread == null) {
        jButton_postNewThread = new JButton();
        jButton_postNewThread.setBounds(new Rectangle(682, 118, 230, 36));
        jButton_postNewThread.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        jButton_postNewThread.setText("Post New Thread");
        jButton_postNewThread
                .addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                        getJFrame().dispose();
                        eForumPostThread myWindow = new eForumPostThread(
                                userName);
                        myWindow.getJFrame().setVisible(true);
                    }
                });
    }
    return jButton_postNewThread;
}


public void SetUpTopicDetails() {
    db.setUp("IT Innovation Project");
    String sql = "Select topic_title,topic_description,topic_by from forumTopics WHERE topic_id = "
            + topicId + "";
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    resultSet = db.readRequest(sql);
    try {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            jLabel_topicTitle.setText(resultSet.getString("topic_title"));
            jTextArea_content.setText(resultSet.getString("topic_description"));
            jLabel_topicBy.setText(resultSet.getString("topic_by"));
        }
        resultSet.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

private JButton getJButton_back() {
    if (jButton_back == null) {
        jButton_back = new JButton();
        jButton_back.setBounds(new Rectangle(735, 679, 166, 36));
        jButton_back.setText("Back");
        jButton_back.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        jButton_back.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                getJFrame().dispose();
                eForumMainpage myWindow = new eForumMainpage(userName);
                myWindow.getJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    return jButton_back;
}

/**
 * This method initializes jTextArea_reply
 * 
 * @return javax.swing.JTextArea
 */
private JTextArea getJTextArea_reply() {
    if (jTextArea_reply == null) {
        jTextArea_reply = new JTextArea();
        jTextArea_reply.setBounds(new Rectangle(256, 525, 573, 130));
        jTextArea_reply.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        jTextArea_reply.setLineWrap(true);
    }
    return jTextArea_reply;
}

private JButton getJButton_postReply() {
    if (jButton_postReply == null) {
        jButton_postReply = new JButton();
        jButton_postReply.setBounds(new Rectangle(567, 678, 155, 36));
        jButton_postReply.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        jButton_postReply.setText("Post reply");
        jButton_postReply
                .addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                        submitReply(e);
                    }
                });
    }
    return jButton_postReply;
}

public void submitReply(ActionEvent e) {
    String replyBy = userName;
    String reply = jTextArea_reply.getText();
    if (reply.equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Comment cannot leave blank");
    } else {
        eForumTopics comment = new eForumTopics(replyBy, reply);
        if (comment.createComment() == true) {
            JOptionPane
                    .showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Reply submitted successfully.");
            SetUpJTableComment();
            jTextArea_reply.setText("");
        }
    }

}

private JTable getJTableComment() {
    String header[] = { "Comment", "Reply By" };
    if (jTableComment == null) {
    DefaultTableModel tableModel1 = (DefaultTableModel) jTableComment
            .getModel();
    tableModel1.setColumnIdentifiers(header);

    jTableComment.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(685);
    jTableComment.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(750);

    jTableComment.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMinWidth(97);
    jTableComment.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(100);

    return jTableComment;
}

public void SetUpJTableComment() {
    DefaultTableModel tableModel1 = (DefaultTableModel) jTableComment
            .getModel();
    String[] data = new String[3];
    db.setUp("IT Innovation Project");
    String sql = "Select reply_content,reply_by from forumReplies WHERE reply_topic = "
            + topicId + "";
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    resultSet = db.readRequest(sql);
    tableModel1.getDataVector().removeAllElements();

    try {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            data[0] = resultSet.getString("reply_content");
            data[1] = resultSet.getString("reply_by");
            tableModel1.addRow(data);
        }
        resultSet.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

private JScrollPane getJScrollPaneComment() {
    if (jScrollPaneComment == null) {
        jScrollPaneComment = new JScrollPane();
        jScrollPaneComment.setBounds(new Rectangle(75, 290, 785, 175));
        jScrollPaneComment.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        jScrollPaneComment.setViewportView(getJTableComment());
    }
    SetUpJTableComment();
    return jScrollPaneComment;
}

private JButton getJButton_bookmark() {
    if (jButton_bookmark == null) {
        jButton_bookmark = new JButton();
        jButton_bookmark.setBounds(new Rectangle(487, 119, 186, 36));
        jButton_bookmark.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        jButton_bookmark.setText("Bookmark");
        jButton_bookmark
                .addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                        submitBookmark(e);
                    }
                });
    }
    return jButton_bookmark;
}

public void submitBookmark(ActionEvent e) {
    String bookmarkBy = userName;
    eForumTopics bookmark = new eForumTopics(bookmarkBy);
    if (bookmark.bookmarkThread() == true) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thread has been bookmarked.");
    }
}

private JButton getJButton_myAcc() {
    if (jButton_myAcc == null) {
        jButton_myAcc = new JButton();
        jButton_myAcc.setBounds(new Rectangle(427, 27, 175, 41));
        jButton_myAcc.setText("My account");
        jButton_myAcc.setBorderPainted(false);
        jButton_myAcc.setOpaque(false);
        jButton_myAcc.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        jButton_myAcc.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        jButton_myAcc.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        jButton_myAcc
                .addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                        getJFrame().dispose();
                        eForumMyAcc myWindow = new eForumMyAcc(userName);
                        myWindow.getJFrame().setVisible(true);
                    }
                });
    }
    return jButton_myAcc;
}

private JScrollPane getJScrollPane_areaScrollPane() {
    if (jScrollPane_areaScrollPane == null) {
        jScrollPane_areaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTextArea_reply);
        jScrollPane_areaScrollPane.setBounds(new Rectangle(257, 527, 598, 125));

    }
    return jScrollPane_areaScrollPane;
}

/**
 * This method initializes jTextArea_content    
 *  
 * @return javax.swing.JTextArea    
 */
private JTextArea getJTextArea_content() {
    if (jTextArea_content == null) {
        jTextArea_content = new JTextArea();
        jTextArea_content.setBounds(new Rectangle(75, 224, 678, 47));
    return jTextArea_content;
}

/**
 * This method initializes jScrollPane_descContent  
 *  
 * @return javax.swing.JScrollPane  
 */
private JScrollPane getJScrollPane_descContent() {
    if (jScrollPane_descContent == null) {
        jScrollPane_descContent = new JScrollPane(jTextArea_content);
        jScrollPane_descContent.setBounds(new Rectangle(75, 224, 660, 47));
    }
    return jScrollPane_descContent;
}
```

}

However, the scroll bar keep snapping to the bottom of the textArea instead of first few lines of textArea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot replicate that behavior. You do something else wrong.

Comment: But can you point out what's wrong? I totally have no idea why.

Comment: I copied your code, excepting the last 2 lines and it is working as you need it to. Other than that, I cannot guess what else you are doing without seeing other code.

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Btw, using `setBounds()` etc... is really not a good idea. Using appropriate LayoutManager is the proper way to go.

Comment: I tried to set the view point of text area which is scrollable, to fix at the top when user first enter the window. My current codes of text area is fix at the bottom of textarea. I edited my codes to show example

Comment: @Newbies No-one is able to reproduce your issue based on the pieces of code you provide. Hence my suggestion to make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Basically, the problem is not in what you are showing us. Providing an SSCCE is likely to help us both: you, to spot and locate in which part of the code your problem comes from, us, in being able to reproduce the issue and showing you where the actual problem comes from.

Comment: I edited already. Thats all my codes. Nothing else. The rests of the codes are not related to this.

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: related or not: Do.Not.Use.Null.Layout.

Comment: I am new to this field. Sorry for using the null layout okay? And so far that's what my project guide book'd taught me.

Answer (score 0):

> Thats all my codes. Nothing else. The rests of the codes are not related to this.

Yet, when I run my [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), with the code you have provided us so far, it works like a charm:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestTextArea3 {

    private static final String TEXT = "This \r\n" + "    Is\r\n" + "    A\r\n" + "    Testing\r\n" + "    To\r\n" + "    Test\r\n"
            + "    ScrollPane.";

    private JTextArea jTextArea_content;
    private JScrollPane jScrollPane_descContent;

    private void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestTextArea3.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getJTextArea_content().setText(TEXT);
        frame.add(getJScrollPane_descContent());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getJTextArea_content().scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle());
            }
        });
    }

    private JTextArea getJTextArea_content() {
        if (jTextArea_content == null) {
            // Changed the number of rows so activate scrolling
            jTextArea_content = new JTextArea(3, 30);
            jTextArea_content.setBounds(new Rectangle(75, 224, 678, 47));
        }
        return jTextArea_content;
    }

    private JScrollPane getJScrollPane_descContent() {
        if (jScrollPane_descContent == null) {
            jScrollPane_descContent = new JScrollPane(getJTextArea_content());
            jScrollPane_descContent.setBounds(new Rectangle(75, 224, 660, 47));
        }
        return jScrollPane_descContent;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTextArea3().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you all understand what's my problem? Or I did not explained well?Because my textArea with scrollpane height only allow two rows to be showed. But it keeps showing the last two rows of comments instead of first two rows.

Comment: @Newbies Have you run my example? If so, you will actually see that it only displays 3 rows and does not scroll to the bottom (yet there are 7 lines to be displayed). So, I believe I understood quite well your problem, yet you keep on not showing us a complete working example that reproduce your problem. Based on what you have shown so far, your problem does not show up-->there is something wrong, somewhere else, but not in what you have showed us. I can only say it once more: post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: What does your TestTextArea3.class.getSimpleName() do?

Comment: @Newbies, nothing, it returns "TestTextArea3" as a String, that's all. This is just a simple way for me to distinguish the various frame I run. You can remove that line without modifying the behaviour of the SSCCE.

Comment: But where do I call the initUI method? I do not have main method in that class

Comment: @Newbies You must have a `main` method somewhere (unless you are making an Applet). The example above is just a small example that shows you how it can work. Real applications contain code much more complex, spanned over several classes etc...

Comment: Can you help me fit your codes into my codes? I do not have idea how to implement it.

Comment: Why not, but without seeing more of your code, it will be really hard.

Comment: I put in the whole junk of codes already. There is a table for user to comment and the whole codes seem quite long.

Comment: @Newbies OK, so somewhere you must have something like: `eForumThreadContent forumContent = new eForumThreadContent(...)` and then have `forumContent.getJFrame();...` All that code, put it in a new method called `initUI()` and then instead of directly calling initUI(), use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run() {initUI();}});` And in the method that initialize the textarea, add the code `SwingUtilities... ` that performs the scroll to the top of the JTextArea. My guess is that currently, your UI is created on the Main-Thread and not in the UI-Thread (EDT).

Comment: I cannot find the eForumThreadContent forumContent = new eForumThreadContent(...)

Comment: @Newbies Then just look for "new eForumThreadContent", you must have that line somewhere (unless you are performing dynamic invocation, but I doubt that)

Comment: Can you please help me find and paste out the codes around that line? Because the page itself is called eForumThreadContent. So far what I found is the constructor only

Comment: @Newbies Where do you have the word 'eForumThreadContent' preceeded by the word 'new'? You must have that somewhere. Where do you invoke the constructor of "eForumThreadContent"?

Comment: I invoked the constructor within the class. But unfortunately there is no initialization of my eForumThreadContent

Comment: @Newbies One thing that may simplify all this is to rename your method `main()` into `init()` and then create a new method `main()` containing this: `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run() {init();}});`. This is not pretty but it should solve your problem.